# What is the best way to update/add paragraphs with REST on a node

Tags: 8

I have a node with a paragraph. This paragraph has a couple fields and there can be any number of these paragraphs on a node.

I want to update this node via REST.  This is some of the GET output:

```
"field_region": [
    {
        "target_id": 13,
        "target_type": "taxonomy_term",
        "target_uuid": "2ae47cc7-c1c2-477d-8f23-b124e964f83a",
        "url": "/regions/california"
    }
],
"field_tactic_disbursements": [
    {
        "target_id": 9,
        "target_revision_id": 13,
        "target_type": "paragraph",
        "target_uuid": "1c98b1aa-f443-47fe-baff-1ecd0b499d1f"
    }
],
"field_year": [
    {
        "target_id": 1,
        "target_type": "taxonomy_term",
        "target_uuid": "58f65d10-143f-4a23-9315-52220c433602",
        "url": "/years/2018"
    }
]
```

Based on how this is, it looks like I will have to do a separate PATCH/POST request for each paragraph.   Is there a way to do this in one request?

I'm thinking about creating  a custom Resource to handle this but not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2848878 is an issue that allows to embed paragraphs on a field directly into the main resource.

We developed and use it exclusively for the use case of default_content with hal_json. It will likely not work out of the box with REST and patching/updating entities. But you're welcome to use it as a first step towards that, patches based on that are welcome.